# Pass data from one component to another, via a parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I am new to ReacJS and JavaScript and I am stuck on an issue. I have an application, built of functional components, and what I'm trying to do is query a DB (where the schema is 2 columns, id, and content) from one component, then pass the result of that query (which happens `onClick`, see below) to another sibling component. What I have so far is this:

**App.js:**

```js
const App = () => {
    // *Other functions and states here*

    const [content, setContent] = useState('');

    const getBookContent = useCallback(async () => {
        await fetch('/get_books/${id}')
            .then(response => 
                response.json()
            .then(data => {
                setContent(data.content)
            })
        );
    }, [setContent])

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <NavBar />
            <div>
                <BooksList books={books} getBooksList={getBooksList} getBookContent={getBookContent} />
                <TextEditor getBooksList={getBooksList} getBookContent={content} />
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

`Booklist` is the list of buttons.

```js
const BooksList = ({books, getBooksList, getBookContent}) => {
    // *Other funcs*

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div>{books.map(book => {
                return (
                    <div key={book.content}>
                        <button onClick={() => getBookContent()}>{book.content}</button>
                    </div>
                )
            })}</div>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
```

I think I am on the right sort of lines. However, I think my issue is in the parent element and getting the id for `await fetch('/get_books/${id}')`. I'm not sure how I should set this, or if this is even the correct thing to do.

Comment: Where do you get the id from ?

Comment: That's actually part of the question. I want to get the item at ID and print its content.

Comment: i think you should use `getBookContent(book.id)` in `BookList`  component

Comment: Dear @intRG, do any of the answers help you?

Comment: They seem to be helpful. I will update accordingly as I am going through them now.

Comment: If you -1 this, please let me know why so i can update and/or generalise further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you should use JavaScript [`currying`](https://blog.benestudio.co/currying-in-javascript-es6-540d2ad09400) and you need to read about [`template string`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). let's first fix your `getBookContent` function:

```js
const getBookContent = useCallback(id => async () => {
  await fetch(`/get_books/${id}`)
    .then(response => 
      response.json()
    )
    .then(data =>
      setContent(data.content)
    )
  }, [setContent]);
```

The above `getBookContent` function is a `currying` function that it means after passing the `id` you can have a new function with the new id, the function pass another function. now pass it to the component:

```js
~~~

<BooksList
  books={books}
  getBooksList={getBooksList}
  getBookContent={getBookContent}
/>

~~~
```

And inside the `BookList` component:

```js
<>
  <div>
    {books.map(({ content, id }) => (
        <div key={content}>
          <button
           onClick={getBookContent(id)}
          >
            {content}
          </button>
        </div>
      )
    )}
  </div>
</>
```

Excuse me for changing your code style, I just make it easier to read based on Airbnb ESLint standards.

Comment: Hey man, this is actually a great answer. I learnt a lot from this. Im not sure why or what the difference is, but i had to put `const getBookContent = useCallback(id => async () => {` as  `const getBookContent = useCallback(async (id) => {` and it worked perfect. Cheers man!

Comment: @intRG, you're welcome, One of the benefits is better readability. when you create a _currying function_ in fact, you create a function that returns another function, with your version, actually, it is the same as me but in the deep level of the child you create another function inside the `onClick`, you can collect whole the function in the higher level and make your other codes much easier to read. for more information read [this link](is.gd/EDjjFx): **The main benefit of currying is when you need to use the same call with some of the same parameters a lot. **

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `Template literals` instead of **single quotes**. and you have to provide the id through the function parameters. try this:

```
const getBookContent = useCallback(async (id) => {
    await fetch(`/get_books/${id}`)
        .then(response => 
            response.json()
        .then(data => {
            setContent(data.content)
        })
    );
}, [setContent])
```

And then call it in your component like this:

```
this.props.getBookContent(ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use backticks:

```
fetch(`/get_books/${id}`)
```

For the id, you could do it that way:

```
<div key={book.id}>
  <button onClick={() => getBookContent(book.id)}>{book.content}</button>
</div>
```